# Django cannot find one template out three - strange behavior

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am currently going through the Django tutorial and when I tried to run the webserver at the middle of part 4 I stumbled accross this error: TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/2/

The strange thing is that the other two file work fine, just not the detail.html (see screenshots)

I checked the spelling over and over as well als polls/view.py and polls/url.py - but I have no clue as to origin of this seemingly erratic behavior.
I also the polls/**pycache** content after reading about that in another post. Nothing.
And btw, the same behavior occurs on my local machine as well as on pythonanywhere.com

What did I do wrong?

Thanks.

Oh, is there anything you need like the views.py, urls.py ...?

[image: Error]

[image: Templates folder content]

Comment: why it is asking for `detail.htm`, but in your directory, it is `detail.html`?

Comment: Thanks. That was it what I did not see. Because I misspelled it in polls/view.py :-(

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo you should spell detail.html not detail.htm

Comment: Thanks. I already know due to the comment of @Bedilbek